# как выполнить sql скрипт в query analyzer

Tags: sql, sql-server, сервер

Нужно выполнить sql скрипт в query analyzer в автоматическом режиме, например, через командную строку. Такое возможно? Например, из программы будет вызываться cmd с указанием скрипта. Возможно ли такие действия с query analyzer? Или запустить query analyzer из cmd и указать автоматически выполнить определённый скрипт.

Comment: Query analyzer — это ведь про какую-то очень древнюю версию SQL Server? Вообще-то, для Вашей задачи есть sqlcmd, но с какой версии он появился, с ходу не скажу.

Comment: @Yaant С 2005, я использую 2000 и там есть osql, он работает аналогично equry? Мне важно обрабатывать скрипты также как в query analyzer

Comment: C 2000 дела иметь не приходилось, но судя по описанию, osql - это аналог sqlcmd, тоже позволяет выполнять sql скрипты

Comment: @Yaant Точно также как и query analyzer? Мне нужно чтобы в нём выполнилось всё также без каких либо ошибок как и в query analyzer.

Comment: Ну, так и в том и в другом случае текст скрипта отправляется на сервер, и тот его выполняет. Почему должна быть какая-то разница?

Comment: @Yaant Не знаю, я пытался когда-то выполнить скрипт не прямо с сервера и использовал для этого библиотеку для Java. Так  там была нужна определённая структура документа для успешного выполнения. Хоть и прекрасно выполнялось в query